# How to test ES6 promises with Jasmine 2.0?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, promise, es6-promise

I have a function that returns a ([probably shimmed)](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) ES6 promise and I want to write a Jasmine test that checks it successfully resolves and the resolved value is correct. How would I do that?

This is the way I've found at the moment, but it's boring at the least:

```
describe("Promises", function() {
  it("should be tested", function(done) {
    var promise = functionThatReturnsAPromise();
    promise.then(function(result) {
      expect(result).toEqual("Hello World");
      done();
    }, function() {
      expect("promise").toBe("successfully resolved");
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

There is also a library called [jasmine-as-promised](https://github.com/ThomasBurleson/jasmine-as-promised) which seemed helpful, but sadly it does not work in Jasmine 2.0 as it uses `runs()` which has been removed.

Is there any comfortable solution already developed for testing promises in Jasmine 2.0?

Comment: Feedback would be nice

Comment: I looked into Mocha, but it seems it only supports very recent browsers (e.g. IE9/10+ depending on the assert library), which I would rather avoid at the moment (also, I would have to rewrite all the assertions into a new format). The itP solution is not the most appealing but it may work; I haven't had time enough to test it thoroughly though. I'm also waiting for help with another library which is intended to help testing RSVP promises (ES6 Promises are based on RSVP) https://github.com/jasmine-addons/jasmine_rsvp/issues/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly? I'd use Mocha. In Mocha you can simply return a promise and the syntax is very similar since you're using Mocha's syntax for asynchronous testing already. It would look something like:

```
describe("Promises", function() {
  it("should be tested", function() {
    var promise = functionThatReturnsAPromise();
    return promise.then(function(result) {
      expect(result).toEqual("Hello World");
    }, function() {
      expect("promise").toBe("successfully resolved");
    });
  });
});
```

However, if you're stuck with native promises and you can't use mocha - what you have is probably the only alternative really, you can extract the pattern into a method:

```
function itP(description, itfn){
    it(description, function(done){
        var result = itfn(); // call the inner it
        if(result.then) { // if promise was returned
            result.then(done, function(e){
                throw new Error("Async rejection failed " + e.message); 
            }); // resolve means done, reject is a throw
        } else {
            done(); // synchronous
        }
    }); 
}

itP("something", function(){
   return Promise.reject(); // this turns into a failed test
});
```

Comment: Finally, I ended making something like that. Additionally, it supports dependencies between test cases. https://gist.github.com/ntrrgc/b7fb84c909c03a7b2ca3

Comment: You rock! Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 3):

Little late to the party here, but in case others find this question (as did I) - here's a new answer: Use my '[jasmine-es6-promise-matchers](https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-es6-promise-matchers)' component. Using it, your test above would look like this:

```
var promise = functionThatReturnsAPromise();
expect(promise).toBeResolvedWith("Hello World");
```

It's available on Bower and NPM (just `install jasmine-es6-promise-matchers`).

Comment: Much appreciated! Your PR was released as version 2.0.2.